# Why does mypy say I have too many arguments

Tags: python, mypy

I've got a class which has a method that creates instances of the class.

```
class Bar:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, foo: int):
        return cls(foo)

    def __init__(self, foo: int) -> None:
        pass
```

When I run mypy against it, it says `mypytest.py:4: error: Too many arguments for "Bar"`

It seems like a bug to me, because this works fine

```
class Bar:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, foo):
        return cls(foo)

    def __init__(self, foo: int) -> None:
        pass
```

I don't understand why a class method which defines the type of a parameter should break the creation of an instance. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple, just place the `__init__` method first. For example this works fine:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo: int) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, foo: int):
        return cls(foo)
```

For some technical reasons, mypy currently behaves unexpectedly in some corner cases if `__init__` (or `__new__`) is not the first method in the class definition. I think I have already seen a similar problem, but can't find an issue on mypy tracker.

Comment: So basically, it's a mypy bug.

Comment: @user2357112 Filed as a bug: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4290

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I typically like my statics / class methods first, but I'd rather have a clean mypy bill of health.